# Expandable List View expands current view and unselected view Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

This is the code, I used to call expandable list view. I am facing a problem from this, i.e. if I expand one group, it expands other view. Similarly if I close expandable list, it closes other view.

```
ProductListAdapter productListAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(activity,products_per_order);
holder.listview.setExpanded(true);
holder.listview.setAdapter(productListAdapter);
```

This is my Custom Expandable listview.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

    public class CustomExpanaableListview extends ExpandableListView {

        boolean expanded = false;

        public CustomExpanaableListview(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public CustomExpanaableListview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public CustomExpanaableListview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                        int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public boolean isExpanded() {
            return expanded;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
            if (isExpanded()) {
                // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
                // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
                // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
                int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                        Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
                params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
            } else {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }

        public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
            this.expanded = expanded;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which tutorial have u followed

Comment: @AnilDS Previously i used Base Adapter and later I used Expandable Listview Adapter,its works fine.But i used as default android (Expandable listview) & height as wrap content,it shows only one value in list.later i gave custom size.here i got stucked,if i gave as 150dp and if group has one value ,list is too big,so i used custom expandable class .here i have an issue,if i expand certain group ,random group also opening in listview.